# How to install SSL certificate to consume a client web-services?

Tags: java, spring-boot, cxf, x509certificate

I am trying to consume a web-services from a client using apache cxf in spring boot.

For MTF and production environment client has provided few certificates (x509 Certificates)

in the form of

```
Folder A / 

xxxx.cer  |  xxxx.crt |  xxxx.p7b | xxxx.p7c | xxxx-ext-root-ca.crt | xxxx-ext-sub.ca.crt


Folder B(Entrust_L1K) / 

xxxx_g2_ca.crt | entrust_l1k.crt
```

how to set-up /install all these certificate so that i would be able to create a connection to my client.

Current Exception i am getting is :

> SSLException / handshake_failuer